# Setter for class vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

```
void setVector(vector<string> aStringVec)
{

    for(std::vector<string>:: iterator s = str1.vec.begin(); s != str1.vec.end(); ++s)
    {
        classVector.pushback(*s);
    }

}
```

If I do classVector = aStringVec, classVector will point to the pointer to the first element of aStringVec, since vectors are considered to be arrays, and may disappear, because it's on the stack, right?

So is this the right way to write a setter for a class vector, and can I call it anywhere?

Comment: Vector is _not_ an array, so `aStringVec` is not a pointer. You want your function signature to look like this: `void setVector(vector<string>& aStringVec)`. Then it'll work the way you want it to.

Comment: well, i don't have to, but yes it's more efficient. +1 And probably you are right, but I don't think we can just directly assign a vector X to a class vector though, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Make this an answer.

Comment: @OnTheFly You're wrong ;-) You can certainly assign vectors, including from a parameter to a member. You might want to either pass by reference or move though, to minimise unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to set the thing, the best option would be something like

```
void setVector(vector<string> aStringVec)
{
  classVector.swap(aStringVec);
}
```

This ensures that `classVector` holds a copy of the contents of the function argument.

What you are trying to do in your code is append elements to `classVector`, while incurring an unnecessary copy of the whole input vector.

Comment: Is this better or worse than `classVector = std::move(aStringVec)`?

Comment: @AlanStokes Probably about the same. The original data of `classVector` has to be cleared in both cases, and the rest is  simple O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop at all for appending elements to an existing vector. Use [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

```
void setVector(vector<string> const& aStringVec)
{
  classVector.insert(classVector.end(), aStringVec.begin(), aStringVec.end());
}
```

I changed the function argument to a `const&`. `const` because you're not going to modify the input vector within your function, and you should pass by reference instead of by value to avoid unnecessary copying.

Instead if you want to replace the contents of `classVector` with that of the input argument's, then your function should be

```
void setVector(vector<string> aStringVec)
{
  classVector = std::move(aStringVec);
}
```

In this case you should pass the argument by value because you're going to move from it within the function.

Comment: The semantics are different though. The first one is not really a setter, it is an appender.

Comment: @juan I agree, but the OP has a loop calling `push_back` without a prior call to `clear`, which is why I thought maybe he does want to append, and not replace the contents.